# iMacros : retrieve a iMacros variable, and use within Javascript

Tags: imacros

on iMacros, it is possible to retrieve a javascript variable to iMacros.

Like this:
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var ... ;")

But I have been looking for several days how do the opposite? I found nothing in the documentation or elsewhere on the www.
retrieve a IMacros variable, and use within Javascript, Is this possible?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `{{VARNAME}}` inside your javascript:

```
SET x "hello"
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var x='{{x}}'; x+' world'")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```

It'll alert `hello world`

Answer (score 2):

Using `!EXTRACT`

You can add value to `!EXTRACT` var in .iim file, then use `iimGetLastExtract()` to get this value.

For example:

In .iim file:

```
SET !EXTRACT "123"
```

In .js file:

```
var str = iimGetLastExtract()
alert(str)
```